# Vertical v-toggle-btn in Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I know that Vuetify.js has horizontal v-toggle-btn. Is it possible to make it vertical ?

[Here](https://vuetifyjs.com/components/buttons#example-4) is an example of horizontal v-toggle-btn

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thank you for the information from AndrewHarvey

> It appears in one of the newer releases the class named changed, it's now `.v-btn-toggle`

Since [Vuetify defined `.btn-toggle`'s `display` as `inline-flex`](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/dev/src/stylus/components/_button-toggle.styl#L18), you can simply add

```
.btn-toggle {
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

to your stylesheet to achieve [vertical display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) of button items.

Check pen [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YEzppN)

Comment: It appears in one of the newer releases the class named changed, it's now `.v-btn-toggle`

Comment: @AndrewHarvey Thanks. I added it into the answer.